# Must Declare the Scalar Value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I am kinda new to stored procedure and scalar values. Somehow I came up with a thread wherein I need to convert my stored procedure to scalar value in order to produce the output I wanted. I tried converting my stored procedure into a function and now I am getting the error **Must declare the scalar value @---**

The code is

```
Create Function fn_logs(
@Month varchar(50)
,@Year varchar(50)
,@date_from datetime
,@date_to datetime)

RETURNS @Logs TABLE 
(
    -- Columns returned by the function
    UserID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    Fullname nvarchar(max) NULL, 
    Description nvarchar(250) NULL, 
    Department nvarchar(250) NULL, 
    DepartmentHead nvarchar(250) NULL,
    Position nvarchar(250) NULL, 
    Date nvarchar(250) NULL, 
    Month1 nvarchar(250) NULL,
    Year1 nvarchar(250) NULL,
    AMIN nvarchar(250) NULL, 
    AMOUT nvarchar(250) NULL, 
    PMIN nvarchar(250) NULL,
    PMOUT nvarchar(250) NULL
)

begin

DECLARE @AM DATETIME , @AM_MID DATETIME ,@AM_OUT DATETIME, @PM DATETIME,@PM_MID DATETIME,@PM_OUT DATETIME, @ABSENT NVARCHAR, @Four INt, @IN_AM DATETIME, @OUT_AM DATETIME,@IN_PM DATETIME,@OUT_PM DATETIME; 
SET @AM= '12:01:00 AM'
SET @AM_MID = '10:00:00 AM';
SET @AM_OUT = '12:59:59 PM';
SET @PM = '12:00:00 PM';
SET @PM_MID = '3:00:00 PM';
SET @PM_OUT = '11:59:59 PM';

SET @IN_AM = '8:00:00 AM';
SET @OUT_AM = '12:00:00 PM';

SET @IN_PM = '1:00:00 PM';
SET @OUT_PM = '5:00:00 PM';
SET @ABSENT = 'ABSENT';

SET @Four = 4;


INSERT into @Logs
Select 
@UserID= usrinfo.ID,
@Fullname=usrinfo.Name, 
@Description=usrinfo.Description,
@Department=grop.Description, 
@DepartmentHead=grop.DepartmentHead, 
@Position=grop.HeadPosition, 
@Date=FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime), 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 
@Month1=DATENAME(month, auth.TransactionTime),
@Year1=DATEPART(year, auth.TransactionTime),
@AMIN=max(case when auth.FunctionKey = '1' and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') <= @AM_MID and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') >= @AM then FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') end) ,
@AMOUT=min(case when auth.FunctionKey = '2'  and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') >= @AM_MID and  FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') <= @AM_OUT  then FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') end) ,
@PMIN=max(case when auth.FunctionKey = '1'  and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') >= @PM and  FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') <= @PM_MID  then FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') end),
@PMOUT=min(case when auth.FunctionKey = '2'  and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') >= @PM_MID and  FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') <= @PM_OUT  then FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') end)

from NGAC_AUTHLOG as auth INNER JOIN
     NGAC_USERINFO as usrinfo ON usrinfo.ID = auth.UserID INNER JOIN
     NGAC_GROUP as grop ON grop.ID = usrinfo.GroupID 

where auth.AuthResult ='0' AND usrinfo.GroupID = '1'  AND DATENAME(month, auth.TransactionTime)=@Month AND DATEPART(year, auth.TransactionTime)=@Year AND FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime), 'MM/dd/yyyy') between @date_from and @date_to

group by FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime), 'MM/dd/yyyy'),usrinfo.ID, usrinfo.Name,grop.DepartmentHead, grop.HeadPosition, grop.Description, usrinfo.ID, usrinfo.Description, DATEPART(year, auth.TransactionTime), DATENAME(month, auth.TransactionTime);
RETURN;
end;
```

The stored procedure is about getting the Employee Logs in a specific day. It consists of three databases for the Employee information while the time is being displayed by selecting the **max()** and **min()** time of Employee depending on the time range manually selected. The error persists in the **Insert** method after **Select**

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: `RETURNS @LogsTABLE` - should be `RETURNS @Logs TABLE` , space is missing.

Comment: @Abhishek there is a space there. Typographical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `INSERT` statement with this:

```
insert into @Logs
select 
        usrinfo.ID,
        usrinfo.Name, 
        usrinfo.Description,
        grop.Description, 
        grop.DepartmentHead, 
        grop.HeadPosition, 
        FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime), 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 
        DATENAME(month, auth.TransactionTime),
        DATEPART(year, auth.TransactionTime),
        max(case when auth.FunctionKey = '1' and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') <= @AM_MID and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') >= @AM then FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') end) ,
        min(case when auth.FunctionKey = '2'  and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') >= @AM_MID and  FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') <= @AM_OUT  then FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') end) ,
        max(case when auth.FunctionKey = '1'  and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') >= @PM and  FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') <= @PM_MID  then FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') end),
        min(case when auth.FunctionKey = '2'  and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') >= @PM_MID and  FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') <= @PM_OUT  then FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') end)

from NGAC_AUTHLOG as auth INNER JOIN
     NGAC_USERINFO as usrinfo ON usrinfo.ID = auth.UserID INNER JOIN
     NGAC_GROUP as grop ON grop.ID = usrinfo.GroupID 

where auth.AuthResult ='0' 
      and usrinfo.GroupID = '1'  
      and DATENAME(month, auth.TransactionTime)=@Month 
      and DATEPART(year, auth.TransactionTime)=@Year 
      and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime), 'MM/dd/yyyy') between @date_from and @date_to
```

The way you have it, you are only assigning values to those variables. The `SELECT` in that case is only working as a `SET`:

```
declare @SomeVar int

select @SomeVar = 5 -- this is just setting a value to the variable
set @SomeVar = 5 -- same as this
```

You don't need the additional variables (`@UserID, @Fullname` etc.) in that scenario.

Comment: So I was doing it the wrong way. I was adding additional variables in it. Thanks for the help. Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I've commented the code below adding an explanation about your errors

```
Create Function fn_logs(
@Month varchar(50)
,@Year varchar(50)
,@date_from datetime
,@date_to datetime)

RETURNS @Logs TABLE --error here previous was @LogsTABLE
(
    -- Columns returned by the function
    UserID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    Fullname nvarchar(max) NULL, 
    Description nvarchar(250) NULL, 
    Department nvarchar(250) NULL, 
    DepartmentHead nvarchar(250) NULL,
    Position nvarchar(250) NULL, 
    Date nvarchar(250) NULL, 
    Month1 nvarchar(250) NULL,
    Year1 nvarchar(250) NULL,
    AMIN nvarchar(250) NULL, 
    AMOUT nvarchar(250) NULL, 
    PMIN nvarchar(250) NULL,
    PMOUT nvarchar(250) NULL
)

begin

DECLARE @AM DATETIME , @AM_MID DATETIME ,@AM_OUT DATETIME, @PM DATETIME,@PM_MID DATETIME,@PM_OUT DATETIME, @ABSENT NVARCHAR, @Four INt, @IN_AM DATETIME, @OUT_AM DATETIME,@IN_PM DATETIME,@OUT_PM DATETIME; 
SET @AM= '12:01:00 AM'
SET @AM_MID = '10:00:00 AM';
SET @AM_OUT = '12:59:59 PM';
SET @PM = '12:00:00 PM';
SET @PM_MID = '3:00:00 PM';
SET @PM_OUT = '11:59:59 PM';

SET @IN_AM = '8:00:00 AM';
SET @OUT_AM = '12:00:00 PM';

SET @IN_PM = '1:00:00 PM';
SET @OUT_PM = '5:00:00 PM';
SET @ABSENT = 'ABSENT';

SET @Four = 4;


INSERT into @Logs (
    UserID, 
    Fullname, 
    Description, 
    Department, 
    DepartmentHead,
    Position, 
    Date, 
    Month1,
    Year1,
    AMIN, 
    AMOUT, 
    PMIN,
    PMOUT
)
Select --You cant use variable assignment in an insert+subquery
usrinfo.ID,
usrinfo.Name, 
usrinfo.Description,
grop.Description, 
grop.DepartmentHead, 
grop.HeadPosition, 
FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime), 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 
DATENAME(month, auth.TransactionTime),
DATEPART(year, auth.TransactionTime),
max(case when auth.FunctionKey = '1' and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') <= @AM_MID and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') >= @AM then FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') end) ,
min(case when auth.FunctionKey = '2'  and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') >= @AM_MID and  FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') <= @AM_OUT  then FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') end) ,
max(case when auth.FunctionKey = '1'  and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') >= @PM and  FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') <= @PM_MID  then FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') end),
min(case when auth.FunctionKey = '2'  and FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') >= @PM_MID and  FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') <= @PM_OUT  then FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime, 8),'hh:mm:ss tt') end)

from NGAC_AUTHLOG as auth INNER JOIN
     NGAC_USERINFO as usrinfo ON usrinfo.ID = auth.UserID INNER JOIN
     NGAC_GROUP as grop ON grop.ID = usrinfo.GroupID 

where auth.AuthResult ='0' AND usrinfo.GroupID = '1'  AND DATENAME(month, auth.TransactionTime)=@Month AND DATEPART(year, auth.TransactionTime)=@Year AND FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime), 'MM/dd/yyyy') between @date_from and @date_to

group by FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, auth.TransactionTime), 'MM/dd/yyyy'),usrinfo.ID, usrinfo.Name,grop.DepartmentHead, grop.HeadPosition, grop.Description, usrinfo.ID, usrinfo.Description, DATEPART(year, auth.TransactionTime), DATENAME(month, auth.TransactionTime);
RETURN;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It also works perfectly.